# Expo SQLite unable to query DB

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm currently having a problem trying to query a DB in Expo SQLite.

In my app.js file I get the database from an external source like so:

```
// load DB for expo
FileSystem.downloadAsync(
  'http://example.com/downloads/data.sqlite',
  FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'data.sqlite'
)
.then(({ uri }) => {
  console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

I can confirm the database is downloaded in console I get:

```
Finished downloading to  file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6E1347A8-187E-4EF3-B360-60A0B24E1008/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fexpo-sqlite-example-36a92625-6e95-41cc-af6d-a47fc254b237/data.sqlite
this is5507
```

I then load this in another component:

```
const db = SQLite.openDatabase('data.sqlite');
```

Then I run a query like so:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'SELECT * FROM dr_report_templates',
        [],
        (success) => console.log(success),
        (error) => console.error(error)
      );
    })
  }
```

I've confirmed that dr_report_templates is in the database.
The error I get is this:

```
h {
  "_complete": false,
  "_error": null,
  "_running": true,
  "_runningTimeout": false,
  "_sqlQueue": t {
    "first": undefined,
    "last": undefined,
    "length": 0,
  },
  "_websqlDatabase": h {
    "_currentTask": _ {
      "errorCallback": [Function anonymous],
      "readOnly": false,
      "successCallback": [Function anonymous],
      "txnCallback": [Function anonymous],
    },
    "_db": n {
      "_closed": false,
      "_name": "data.sqlite",
    },
    "_running": true,
    "_txnQueue": t {
      "first": undefined,
      "last": undefined,
      "length": 0,
    },
    "version": "1.0",
  },
}
```

In my device I get:

```
console.error: {"_websqlDatabase": {"version":"1.0","_db":...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

success and error callbacks take two parameters, first is a transaction and second is result/error

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
const getTemplates = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'SELECT * FROM dr_report_templates',
        [],
        (txObj, { rows: { _array } }) => {
          resolve(_array);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
          reject(error);
        }
      );
    });
  });
};
```